# PHP Laravel - Validating webhook signature

Tags: php, laravel, php-8

I have an API who sends a signature in the request header (`X-Signature`):

The value of the header is SHA256withRSA signature of request's body.

The documentation around the webhook have an example on how to validate:

```c
bool Verify(string publicKey, string payload, string signature)
{
    var key = (ICipherParameters)new PemReader(new StringReader(publicKey)).ReadObject();
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");
    signer.Init(false, key);
    signer.BlockUpdate(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return signer.VerifySignature(Convert.FromBase64String(signature));
}
```

I am trying to validate the webhook using PHP/Laravel though. This is my code:

```php
public function isValid(Request $request) : bool
{
    $signature = $request->header('X-Signature');

    if (! $signature) {
        return false;
    }

    $signingSecret = ""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIIBIjAN......";


    $computedSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $request->getContent(), $signingSecret);

    return hash_equals($signature, $computedSignature);
}
```

The above `isValid()` function returns false on every request I try to make.

This is the output `$request->all()`:

```json
"webhookType": "test" ,
"companyId": "8628731d-ddb5-4c8f-82b1-823734962c1e" ,
"documentId": "3807f10a-9eeb-4818-a935-c8990bd50f71"
```

And the `X-Signature` is indeed in the request:

```
"X-signature": "IY/QvzSDyV...."
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check if this could helpyou: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using openssl:

```php
public function isValid(Request $request, WebhookConfig $config): bool
{

    $signature = $request->header('X-Signature');
    if (! $signature) {
        return false;
    }



    $publicKey = "...";

    if (!$publicKey) {
        return false;
    }

    $payload = $request->getContent();

    $signature = base64_decode($signature);

    $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($publicKey);

    $result = openssl_verify($payload, $signature, $publicKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

    if ($result === 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is 'WebhookConfig $config' (what lib) and where is it used here? Are you using any SDKs?

Comment: @gvanto Good catch, it is actually not used. I originally planned to have a `env` file containing the config values, but ended up just hardcoding them in. The above method was actually the result of GPT-3. So entirely created by AI.....